# need a method to print a 2d array that works for this program

Tags: java

So like the title says, im trying to make a method that prints a 2d array that i have already populated with another method.  so basically this is what i have for my populate method.

```
public void populate() {
        int num = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
                this.values[i][j] = num;
                ++num;
            }
        }
    }
```

that is in a class called Array_two now right below this in that same class i have this.

```
static void printMatrix(int[][] grid) {
        for(int r=0; r<grid.length; r++) {
           for(int c=0; c<grid[r].length; c++)
               System.out.print(grid[r][c] + " ");
           System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

in my main i have this

```
Array_two my2dArray = new Array_two(10,10);
            my2dArray.populate();
            Array_two.printMatrix(my2dArray);
```

everything works except for that print statement, ive been playing around with it because i know its a problem with the types and im probably making a really dumb mistake i just for some reason cant figure out what im doing at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

`Array_two.printMatrix(my2dArray);`

do

`Array_two.printMatrix(my2dArray.values);`

Because `my2dArray` is an object not a 2d array.